# is it possible to redirect from a middleware element?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a little middleware object that redirects on specified url's, but I can't find alot of information about it so I don't know if it's even possible or do I have to implement it as a Rule?

**Code**:

```
public class RedirectMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _request;
    private readonly RedirectMiddlewareConfig _config;

    public RedirectMiddleware(RequestDelegate request, RedirectMiddlewareConfig config)
    {
        _request = request;
        _config = config;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        string path = context.Request.Path.ToString().ToLower();

        if (_config.Paths.ContainsKey(path))
        {
            string url = _config.Paths[path].ToLower();

            context.Response.Redirect(url, true);
        }

        await _request(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `return` after the `Redirect` line so you don’t invoke `_request`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin thanks!